# How to use dictionaries to store a list of data from a file and do a check if data occurs in multiple keys?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and what I am trying to achieve is read json and store in a dictionary.  I need to store a common variable index, a change variable index and a list of changes for the change variable.

So far I get the json message and set the common variable index and append it to a list. I then store the change variable in the same list before appending all the changes for it.

For example:  If I had two authors and for each author they wrote three books, for each book I need to store the changes they made(store page numbers changed).  Once all that data is stored, I would need to loop over all the changes for each book and see if they appear in the other books.  Then print out the author and the book that has the same page number changed.   (I know it is not the best example, but you get the point.

Reading in from a file:

```
        list = []
        item = []
        with open("tst.file",'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                authorRegEx = re.search(r"\([A-Z0-9-]+)",line)
                author = authorRegEx.group(0).strip("()") 
                list.append(author)
                bookItemRegEx = re.search(r"\*[A-Z0-9-]+\*",line)
                book = bookItemRegEx.strip("*")
                list.append(book)
                ***Then call a rest api to get the json message****
                modifiedPages = api call
                for i in range(len(modifiedPages['values'])):
                    pageNumber = modifiedPages['value'][i]['page']
                    item.append(pageNumber)
                list.append(item)
                item=[]
          print list
```

Which outputs

```
['Author1','book1,[u'page1','page2','page3'],'Author1','book2',     [u'page2,page4'],'Author2','book1'[u'page2','page3']]
```

At this point I am at a loss as to what to do next.  I need to loop over the page(x) variable for each author and book and check if it appears in the others.  Then need to print out which Author, book and page that contains the same page(x) number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bookItemRegEx = re.search(r"\*[A-Z0-9-]+\*,line)`, did you mean `bookItemRegEx = re.search(r"\*[A-Z0-9-]+\*",line)` (missing end quotation mark)?

Comment: yes I forgot to put that when typing this out.  Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.  Is the code you posted relevant to ```what to do next```?  Have you been successful at  using ```dictionaries to store a list of data from a file```?

Comment: I need to store for each author there will be a set of books.  For each book there will be a set of changed pages.  Once that is all stored, I then need to loop over them and print out any pages that are in the same book.  So if page 2 is in book1 and book2 I need to print out Author1,Author2->book1,book2->pages the same

Comment: String1=Author1 Book1 Page1 Page2
    String2=Author2 Book2 Page2 Page3 Page4
    String3=Author2 Book3 Page2 Page5 Page6 Page3

Once these are read in from the json message I need to check if the same Page is in any other Book(x).  Afterwards need to print it out.
For this example:
    Page2 -
    Book1
    Book2

    , Page3 -
    Book2
    Book3